# Setting a background image while using the sign in template

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Student Coder Alert:
I am trying to use the Material-UI Sign in Template.  I am having issues getting a full-screen background to work with it.  Everywhere I try to put the img it is either conflicting with the sign in a container or just will not show up. I am at a loss.

```
function Copyright() {
  return (
    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" align="center">
      {'Copyright © '}
      <Link color="inherit" href="https://material-ui.com/">
        TableTopRP.com
      </Link>{' '}
      {new Date().getFullYear()}
      {'.'}
    </Typography>
    
  );
}

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  paper: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    alignItems: 'center',
    
  },
  avatar: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  form: {
    width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
  },
  submit: {
    margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
  },
}));

export default function SignIn() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs" style={{ backgroundColor: "#f3dcba" }} >
 
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className={classes.paper} >
        <Avatar className={classes.avatar}>
          <LockOutlinedIcon />
        </Avatar>
        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
          Sign in
        </Typography>
        <form className={classes.form} noValidate>
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            id="email"
            label="Email Address"
            name="email"
            autoComplete="email"
            autoFocus
          />
          <TextField
            variant="outlined"
            margin="normal"
            required
            fullWidth
            name="password"
            label="Password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
          />
          <FormControlLabel
            control={<Checkbox value="remember" color="primary" />}
            label="Remember me"
          />
          <Button
            type="submit"
            fullWidth
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            className={classes.submit}
          >
            Sign In
          </Button>
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                Forgot password?
              </Link>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Link href="#" variant="body2">
                {"Don't have an account? Sign Up"}
              </Link>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </div>
      <Box mt={8}>
        <Copyright />
      </Box>

    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is, your `max-width` of `Container` component is `xs` only.

So my solution is, you can have a wrapper out of that `Container` and use whatever background you want.

Example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-blackwell-t1uie?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you so much!!!  I was trying that and couldn't figure out what I was doing wrong....  I wasn't putting the closing </div> tag outside of the </Container>.   You just solved something ive been working on all day.